# How to decode tonic-web responses

Tags: grpc-web, rust-tonic

I'm using tonic-web combined with a React web frontend using @protobuf-ts/grpcweb-transport and @protobuf-ts/plugin.

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kerKXChDmsE (no need to watch)

The tutorial is comprised of:

https://github.com/dreamsofcode-io/grpcalculator-rs and https://github.com/dreamsofcode-io/grpcalculator-web

I've been successful in getting the request payload from the browser network tab and running it through a tool like https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/ but I've also used some CLI tools in conjunction with the proto file itself to get a more informative output.

When I was trying the CLI approach I was going through https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/634

However, I can't seem to do the same with the response. The CLI tools say they can't parse the response and the web based tool doesn't provide anything meaningful. In the issue link I provided it does seem that requests and responses can have differing prefix data and I have accounted for that, or so I think.

I would LOVE to be able to use a tool like https://github.com/SafetyCulture/grpc-web-devtools/ but that seems to be for grpc-web which is not used in the tutorial I'm following. And when I tried was too complicated for me when trying to get it to work with typescript.

I'd love to adopt grpc but I also need to be able to debug it. I understand it will be more cumbersome than json, but right now I can't get it to work at all. I know it should be possible, it's not encrypted, after all the front end can access the data, I know it can since I can see the result on the front end!

How can I decode the responses from tonic-web.

`QUFBQUFBTUl6d0k9Z0FBQUFBOW5jbkJqTFhOMFlYUjFjem93RFFvPQ==` came from the example app and should contain "335" in it.

`QUFBQUFCWUtGRWhsYkd4dklITjBZV05yYjNabGNtWnNiM2NoZ0FBQUFBOW5jbkJqTFhOMFlYUjFjem93RFFvPQ==` comes from my own implementation and should contain "Hello stackoverflow!"

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it is base64 encoded twice. So, first decode from base64:

QUFBQUFCWUtGRWhsYkd4dklITjBZV05yYjNabGNtWnNiM2NoZ0FBQUFBOW5jbkJqTFhOMFlYUjFjem93RFFvPQ==

-->

AAAAABYKFEhlbGxvIHN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3chgAAAAA9ncnBjLXN0YXR1czowDQo=

Then decode this with https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/ and you'll see "Hello stackoverflow!" in the first field.